# Spring data JPA many to many retrieve

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have entities as below. I need to retrieve list of CIDs from CEntity using AEntity's id;

I have to traverse thru AEntity -> ABMapping -> BEntity -> fetch CID from CEntity.

Is there a way to achieve this in JPA or Should I go native query way joining all four tables and get CIDs from CEntity?

Entity A

```
@Entity
public class AEntity {

@Id
private long id;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "ABMapping", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AEntity_ref", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "BEntity_ref", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<BEntity> bEntities = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Entity B

```
@Entity
public class BEntity {

@Id
private long id;

private CEntity cEntity;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bEntities")
private List<AEntity> aEntities;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "cEntityId")
public CEntity getCEntity() {
    return cEntity;
    }
}
```

Entity ABMapping

```
@Entity
public class ABMapping {

@Id
private long id;

@Column(name="AEntity_ref")
private long ARefId;

@Column(name = "BEntity_ref")
private long BRefId;

}
```

Entity C

```
@Entity
public class CEntity {

@Id
private long id;

private String CID;

private List<BEntity> bEntity;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "c", cascade = 
CascadeType.ALL)
public List<BEntity> getBEntities() {
   return bEntity;
}

@Column(name = "CID_column")
public String getCId() {
   return CID;
}

public void setCId(String CID) {
    this.CID = CID;
}

}
```

Comment: what did you try already? it is possible via jpa

Comment: Why do you have an ABMapping entity? It's useless (and problematic, since mapped to the same table as the join table used for the many-to-many association). That said: have you tried anythig. Have you read the documentation of JPQL?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I tried something like this in AEntityRepository which extends CrudRepository to get the Bentities but unsure how to get the CEntity from Bentity.  List<BEntity> findBEntitiesByAEntityId(long Id);

Comment: For anything but trivial queries like findByName, you should use a meaningful method name, annotate the method with the Query annotation, and specify your JPQL query.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok. I have gone thru jpql examples and documentation and come up with below Query. Can you please check what I'm missing here. 
  `select distinct c from CEntity c join c.BEntity b join b.AEntity a where a.id = :id`

Comment: There is no property named BEntity in C. It's a collection, named bEntities. And there is no property AEntity in B. The query should be something like `select distinct c from AEntity a join a.bEntities b join b.cEntity c where a.id = :id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with what @JB Nizet has suggested with.

```
select distinct c from AEntity a join a.bEntities b join b.cEntity c where a.id = :id
```